# Var(XY) goes to zero if Var(X) and Var(Y) go to zero

Tags: statistics, variance

Let $X$ and $Y$ be (possibly dependent) random variables. I want to show that if the variance of $X$ and $Y$ both go to zero, the variance of the product $XY$ also goes to zero. In other words, for any small $\epsilon$, we can make $Var(XY) < \epsilon$ by making $Var(X)$ and $Var(Y)$ small enough.

I have tried to show this by expanding into expectations but I can’t seem to get the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true.  Try $X=Y= \delta^{-1/3}$ with probability $\delta$, $0$ otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this, but maybe I need additional conditions. I mean that the variance of X, Y goes to zero with the expected value unchanged, e.g. if X and Y are sample means then by increasing the sample size.

Comment: You can adjust these slightly so the expected values are $0$: take $X=Y=-\delta^{2/3}/(1-\delta)$ otherwise, instead of $0$.

Comment: Hmm, what if we limit ourselves to discrete distributions and their support must stay the same as the variance goes to zero?